# C++ string replacement function infinite loop

Tags: c++, string

**The project**

I thought that I would make a program that takes a file with the following syntax: `old_word:new_word` to make a change of syntax easier. I have other plans, but right now the core of the program is not working.

**The problem**

I have not used C++ for very long so I am still learning. I am using somebody else's string replace function, but it gets caught in an infinite loop. The function contains some syntax I am not familiar with, so I cannot tell why it is failing. Every other function returns properly.

The string replacement function is listed below:

```
//!Not my work
void replaceAll(std::string& str,  std::string& from,  std::string& to) {
size_t start_pos = 0;
while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) < std::string::npos) {
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    start_pos += to.length();
}
}
```

The program fails on this loop:

```
for(int secInd=0; secInd<members; secInd++)
    {
        replaceAll(line[index],toStrings[secInd],fromStrings[secInd]);
    }
```

`line` is a buffer gotten from the `getline` function. `toStrings` is loaded from a language definition file, and so is fromStrings.

Can anybody tell me why this is going into an infinite loop and possibly tell me how to fix it? The full source is located at http://pastebin.com/zXFFvUSm if you need it.

Comment: Start by changing `< std::string::npos` to `!= std::string::npos`

Comment: And no, StackOverflow is not a human-powered debugger.

Comment: The second argument of the replaceAll function is std::string& from, and the third argument is std::string& to, but when you call it, you are passing in toStrings as the second argument and fromStrings as the third argument.  Is this intentional, or could this by any chance have something to do with it?

Comment: ds1848: That is an issue, yes. And to all of those recommending debuggers, thank you. I had actually never heard of or used a debugger before.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in a debugger.  Beginner (or beginner to a specific language) programmers often overestimate how hard debuggers are to learn and use.  You could have learned enough dbx to solve this problem and done so in the amount of time it took you to ask this question and wait for an answer - yes, they're that easy to use for simple tasks like this.